# How to update table variable in stored procedure from another user defined function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, table-variable

Scenario: user-defined function returns one table.

If that table contains at least one row, one column in the table variable from another stored procedure should get updated.

Should I use cross join on UDF to update table variable?

Comment: Using T-Sql queries ,microsoft sql server

Comment: TVPs must be declared `READONLY` and cannot be updated. You can of course update local table variables before passing them as parameters. From your question it's not clear what, if anything, you're having trouble with.